# Conection Angular 10 + Django Api Rest no render objetcs

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

im trying use Django rest + angular 10, i will show a list of providers in the browser, could someone explain to me why my django api rest objects are not rendering? appear in console but not in html.
im using angular 10, django 2.7, cors, and my localhost.
this is my code.

// app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

//app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor='let provider of providers'>
    <h2>{{ provider.name | uppercase }}</h2>
    <p>{{ provider.procedence }}</p>
    <p>{{ provider.email }}</p>
    <p>{{ provider.telephone }}</p>
</div>
```

// app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProviderService } from './provider.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'conexion';
  providers: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    protected ProviderService: ProviderService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ProviderService.getProviders()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
        this.providers = data['results'];
        console.warn(data)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

// app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProviderService } from './provider.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ProviderService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

// provider.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProviderService {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

  getProviders() {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/provider?format=json');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug Use [Async](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/) and learn how to use it, it's less code and less mistakes. Smart/Dumb components and OnPush Change Detection

Define

```
public providers$: Observable<any>;
```

ngOnInit

```
this.providers$ = this.ProviderService.getProviders();
```

Template

```
{{ providers$ | async | json }}
```